# Upload a variable named file via CURL command line

Tags: regex, file, curl, command-line, upload

I am trying to upload a file to a server using `Curl command line` tool. File which is uploaded is generated by a build tool so its name is variable and depends upon the version of the project.

For example:

> File to be uploaded has name: puppet-14.1.6-snapshot.zip // where 14.1.6 is the version of project

**Here is my (working) CURL command:**

> curl -u admin:admin -F file=@"target/puppet-14.1.6-snapshot.zip" -F name="puppet-core-pkg" -F force=true -F install=true http://myserver.com:4502/service.jsp

The above call works perfectly but I am trying to find an alternative via which i do not need to change the file parameter every time a new version of project goes out.

I have already tried these two

```
file=@"target/puppet-*-snapshot.zip" //Does not work
file=@"target/puppet-[*]-snapshot.zip" //Does not work
```

**Is it possible to use some regex and upload the file which matched the given regex ?**

Comment: The "*" loses it's meaning because there because of the quotes / is not bare. I believe one of the evaluation expansions can be used.

Comment: @user2864740 Absolutely correct. I just wanted to mention that I have already tried them :)

Comment: @user2864740 Can you please provide a simple example of evaluation expression ?

Comment: Hmm, the expansion won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a temporary workaround for it but still not a convincing solution. Here it goes:

```
package_name=$(ls | grep puppet-)

curl -u admin:admin -F file=@"target/$package_name" -F name="puppet-core-pkg" -F force=true -F install=true http://myserver.com:4502/service.jsp
```

I know there is only one file which gets matched to `puppet-` So `package_name` contains the file name which is to be uploaded.

Although this works for me, I am leaving this question open for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only file in the directory? If so, then you can just have a variable get the name of the file in the directory, and then do:

```
curl -u admin:admin -F file="$TheFile" # and so and so forth
```

Comment: No there are other files in the directory as well.